# Background colors stop at 100% but not when screen has to scroll to the right. Any ideas how to fix

Tags: html, css

This is more of a general question; but I notice on some webistes (including stackoverflow) That when content is off the screen and the user has to scroll to the right background images/color stop at 100% of the screen view. Does anyone have a better idea how to fix this.... other than setting max and min widths?

here is a google doc of two different websites to explain what I am talking about.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/133Uek4Fd3G3eB6Zz4CNomPGzARevCUg4fAV4Xhvin-o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You don't have to set a min and a max width to solve this.. only a min width.. as for a better solution, what could possible be easier than setting a min-width?

Comment: I guess I am thinking for a more fluid responsiveness

Answer (score 1):

Josh C's response is spot on. If the elements that have background colours had min-widths that matched the content width (980px in stackoverflow's case) then the issue would be resolved. This is not only the easiest way, but probably the best practice)

Your alternative, if you don't want to set max and min values to your elements that use percentages, would be to not set fixed widths on elements (in the case of stack overflow, it's content width is fixed at 980px, and most everything else is fluid).

If content and it's children used max-width instead of width this problem would disappear.

Alternately, as lookingGlass points out, more fluid responsiveness. 
Add breakpoints so that when your window size is below/above your ideal the site adapts.